How to prevent TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError while swapping using Jupiter api in solana
I have integrated Jupiter swap api on my react app and swapping tokens using Jupiter api but the swap is working sometimes and not working sometimes with TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError.
I was tried to raise prioritizationFeeLamports but not working well yet.
Here are my code.
  const JUPITER_QUOTE_API = 'https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/quote';
  const JUPITER_SWAP_API = 'https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/swap';


  // Step 1: Fetch swap info from Jupiter
  const fetchSwapInfo = async (inputMint: string, outputMint: string, amount: number) => {
    const url = `${JUPITER_QUOTE_API}?inputMint=${inputMint}&outputMint=${outputMint}&amount=${amount}&slippageBps=150&&swapMode=ExactIn&onlyDirectRoutes=false&asLegacyTransaction=false&maxAccounts=64&minimizeSlippage=false`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    return {
        inAmount: data.inAmount,
        otherAmountThreshold: data.otherAmountThreshold,
        quoteResponse: data,
    };
  };

  // Step 2: Fetch swap transaction from Jupiter
  const fetchSwapTransaction = async (
    walletAddress: PublicKey | null,
    recipientAddress: string,
    swapInfo: any
  ) => {
    if (!walletAddress || !recipientAddress || !swapInfo?.quoteResponse) {
        throw new Error('Invalid parameters: Ensure walletAddress, recipientAddress, and swapInfo are defined.');
    }

    const requestBody = {
        userPublicKey: walletAddress.toBase58(),
        destinationTokenAccount: recipientAddress,
        useSharedAccounts: true,
        quoteResponse: swapInfo.quoteResponse,
        allowOptimizedWrappedSolTokenAccount : true,
        asLegacyTransaction : false,
        dynamicComputeUnitLimit : true,
        prioritizationFeeLamports:{
          priorityLevelWithMaxLamports:{
            global:false,
            maxLamports: 4000000,
            priorityLevel: "veryHigh"
          }
        },
        wrapAndUnwrapSol: true,
    };

    const response = await fetch(JUPITER_SWAP_API, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
        const errorText = await response.text();
        throw new Error(`Error fetching swap transaction: ${errorText}`);
    }

    const { swapTransaction, lastValidBlockHeight } = await response.json();
    return { swapTransaction, lastValidBlockHeight };
  };
  // Function to find the fee account and get serialized transactions for the swap

  // Step 3: Send transaction to Solana blockchain
  const sendTransaction = async (swapTransaction: string,  walletAdapter: WalletAdapter) => {
      let  latestBlockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

      // deserialize the transaction
      const swapTransactionBuf = Buffer.from(swapTransaction, 'base64');
      var transaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(swapTransactionBuf);
      console.log(transaction);

      // Set the recent blockhash
      transaction.message.recentBlockhash = latestBlockHash.blockhash;
      
      const signedTransaction = await (walletAdapter as any).signTransaction(transaction);

      // Execute the transaction
      const rawTransaction = transaction.serialize()

      latestBlockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
      const txid = await connection.sendRawTransaction(rawTransaction, {
        skipPreflight: false,
        maxRetries: 5,
      });
      // get the latest block hash
      console.log(`https://solscan.io/tx/${txid}`);
      setIsConfirming(true);
      await connection.confirmTransaction({
        blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
        lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
        signature: txid
      });
      setIsConfirming(false);
      setTransactionLink(`https://solscan.io/tx/${txid}`);
      console.log(`https://solscan.io/tx/${txid}`);
      return txid;
  };

  // Step 4: Main function to swap and send token
  const swapAndSendToken = async (
    walletAdapter: WalletAdapter,
    recipientAddress: string,
    inputMint: string,
    outputMint: string,
    amount: number
  ) => {
    try {
        const walletPublicKey = walletAdapter.publicKey;

        // Step 1: Fetch swap info
        const swapInfo = await fetchSwapInfo(inputMint, outputMint, amount);

        // Step 2: Fetch the swap transaction
        const { swapTransaction, lastValidBlockHeight } = await fetchSwapTransaction(walletPublicKey, recipientAddress, swapInfo);
        console.log(swapTransaction);
        // Step 3: Send the transaction to the blockchain
        let txid = await sendTransaction(swapTransaction,  walletAdapter);

        console.log('$ sent successfully!\n https://solscan.io/tx/' + txid);

        console.log('Swap and send transaction completed successfully.');
        setIsSuccessful(true);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during swap and send:', error);
        setIsBroken(true);
        //alert("Failed! " + error.message);
    }

  };
  const payCoin = async () => {
    if(isProcessing) return;
    setIsProcessing(true);

    const inputToken = token;
    var targetTokenName = data?.transactions?.currency;    
    if(inputToken.name == targetTokenName)
    {
      alert("direct token send, coming soon!")
    }
    else {
      var targetUnitNumber = 0;
      var targetMint = "";
      Tokens.forEach((element) => {
        if (element.name == targetTokenName) {
          targetMint = element.mintAddress;
          targetUnitNumber = element.decimals;
        }
      });
      var merchant_address = data?.transactions?.merchant_address
      //the public solana address
      const accountPublicKey = new PublicKey(
        merchant_address
      );
  
      //mintAccount = the token mint address
      const mintAccount = new PublicKey(
        targetMint
      );
      const account = await connection.getTokenAccountsByOwner(accountPublicKey, {
        mint: mintAccount});
      if(account.value.length==0) {
        alert("can not find merchant account address for this spl token!");
      }
      else {
        await swapAndSendToken(
          walletAdapter,
          account.value[0].pubkey.toString(), // Merchant's USDC address
          inputToken.mintAddress, // Input mint address
          targetMint, // Output mint address
          tokenAmount * (10 ** inputToken.decimals) // Example: 0.1 USDC in micro-lamports
        );
      }

    }
    setIsProcessing(false);
  }

In this code, I added prioritizationFeeLamports and tried to raise the fee to prevent failing transaction but it's failing many times.
How to raise the fee amount for Jupiter transaction?
